# Do $\overline{A}$ and $A$ only have the same limit points in a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space and suppose $A\subseteq X$. Let $\overline{A}$ be the closure of $A$. Do $A$ and $\overline{A}$ have the same limit points in general, or only in a metric space?  The proofs that I have seen all use a notion of distance, and I was wondering if this was a necessary condition, to have some notion of distance.

I haven't found an example of a topological space where they don't have the same limit points, then again, the extent of topologies that I know of are limited.

Comment: This is not true in general. Consider the set $\{a\}$ in the space $\{a, b\}$ with the indiscrete topology. If $A'$ is closed it is true since $\overline{A}'=A'\cup (A')' = A'$.

Comment: @KarthikKannan what is $A'$ and $A''$ meant to be in your example?

Comment: $A'$ denotes the set of limit points of $A$.